# how copy climatology along time dimension in xarray?

Tags: python-xarray

I have an SST climatology(lat,lon,time) where the time dimension is 12 months. I would like to copy the climatology so I have a dataset of say 100 years in which the SST data is simply the climatology repeating every year.

How do I do this? It seems expand_dims only works for new dimensions, not to copy existing dimensions.

Thanks
Ulla

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I'm understanding correctly, you'd essentially like a new dataset with dimensions `(lat, lon, time)` where time has length 1200?

This is a great use case for xarray's [advanced indexing](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/user-guide/indexing.html#more-advanced-indexing) using a DataArray as an indexer. If you select data using a DataArray as an argument to `.sel` or `.isel`, the data will be reshaped using the *values* of the DataArray as the indexer but the *index* of the DataArray in the result.

In this case, you'd like to reindex the data to have repeating values every month. First, we should rename your time dimension to be `month` so we can create a new dimension `time` in the result:

```py
ds = ds.rename({'time': 'month'})
```

I'm assuming here that your dataset's `time` dimension is simply integers from 1..12. In that case, you can use the `.month` attribute of a datetime array:

```py
# create a monthly time series
date_range = xr.cftime_range("2000-01-01", "2099-12-31", freq="MS")

# access the month index (1, 2, ..., 12) for each date:
months = date_range.month

# create a DataArray from the above. The coordinate is the full date range
# and will become the time dim in the result. The values are the months
# that we would like to select from the climatology
selector = xr.DataArray(months, dims=["time"], coords=[date_range])

# select from the climatology, reshaping to be indexed by `time`
time_series = ds.sel(month=selector)
```

Comment: Yes, this worked like a charm, thank you. I did not know about this functionality, is there any examples one can read up one?  <br/>

All I had to add was to make my month indices from 1 to twelve instead of the default date time format. So the final code became:  <br/>

```SST_clim = SST_clim.rename({'time': 'month'})
SST_clim['month']=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
date_range = xr.cftime_range("2006-01-01", "2099-12-31", freq="MS")
months = date_range.month
selector = xr.DataArray(months, dims=["time"], coords=[date_range])
time_series = SST_clim.sel(month=selector)```

Comment: oh ok! glad this helped. for future reference it's really helpful if you can post a preview of your data e.g. by pasting the result of `print(ds)` as a code block into your question. that way, we can have a good idea of what you're working with. the gold standard is a [mre] but that's admittedly difficult in xarray if you're just getting started.